# Typescript - How do you create a GET endpoint with params?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, url, query-string

I am using express and trying to create an API endpoint to accept a GET request like `GET /dogs?breed=GOLDEN&name=rex`.

What is the best approach to pass parameters into a url? While testing, I created two endpoints as shown below. Neither return a success

```
router.get('/dogs?breed=GOLDEN&name=rex', breedAndNameController.fetch);

router.get('/dogs?breed=:breed&name=:name', breedAndNameController.fetch);
```

```
export const fetch = async (req: any, res: any) => {
    try {
        console.log("success")
        return res.status(200).send("success");
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using express?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using express.js (just a guess).

Query-params are not a part of your route.

You have two options now:

**Use query strings**

Using query-string arguments your url looks like this:

```
router.get('/dogs', breedAndNameController.fetch);
```

And your route:

```
 export const fetch = async (req: any, res: any) => {
        try {

  console.log(req. query);
            return res.status(200).send("success");
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    }
```

The call looks like `/dogs?breed=asdf&name=test`

**Use params**

Using params your url looks like this:

```
router.get('/dogs/:breed/:name', breedAndNameController.fetch);
```

which gives you access like this:

```
export const fetch = async (req: any, res: any) => {
    try {

        console.log(req.params)
        return res.status(200).send("success");
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

And your url looks like `/dogs/tset/asdf`.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep your route as `/dogs` and supply the query params when you actually call the query

```
router.get('/dogs', breedAndNameController.fetch);
```

and then you make a request to as `/dogs?breed=GOLDEN&name=rex`